# Combining/Grouping values using dict() in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a list as such:

```
t = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 0],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 43],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 24],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 145],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 249],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 347],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 191],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 46],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 19],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 88],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 181],
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 250]]
```

I'd like to group these together by the first item in the list - so that i have (in either list or dict form is fine, i can convert one to the other):

```
t = [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 750],
    [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 576]]
```

I tried doing `newdict = dict(t)` to group, but newdict just returns the last value in the list, which isn't what I want.

```
newdict = {datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0): 347,
 datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0): 250}
```

I'd like to SUM UP the values for the same datetime.datetime values.

Any suggestions welcome - thanks!

Comment: try `itertools.groupby`

Comment: the calculation of sum in your examples seems to be wrong - it should be 808 for first and 775 for the second

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for this , you can group the list using the first element and then iterate through the grouped lists to sum the second element up.

Example -

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> t = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 0],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 43],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 24],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 145],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 249],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 347],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 191],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 46],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 19],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 88],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 181],
...  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 250]]
>>> x = groupby(t, lambda x1: x1[0])
>>> newt = []
>>> for y, z in x:
...     l1 = []
...     for a in z:
...             l1.append(a[1])
...     newt.append([y,sum(l1)])
...
>>> newt
[[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 808], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 775]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One line code with `groupby()`:

```
list((k, sum(x[1] for x in g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(t), lambda x: x[0]))
```

Use a `dict` to count:

```
count_dict = {}
for key, value in t:
    count_dict[key] = count_dict.get(key, 0) + value
```

or `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
count_dict = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in t:
    count_dict[key] += value
```

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {}
for el in t:
    if el[0] not in d:
        d[el[0]] = el[1]
    else:
        d[el[0]] += el[1]

print(d)
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer. Code-only answer are not well received.